# sqlite exe : database file path has hyphen : "unknown option: -"

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3-python

I am new to SQLITE. I am trying to open a database through Sqlite3.exe shell. My database file path has hyphen in it..
on entering
.open C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive - batch\db.sqlite3

i am getting below error

unknown option: -

can anyone help..

I tried double quote around path but in that case I am getting

Error: unable to open database

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing

1. backward slashes to forward
2. adding double quotes
   worked...

below is the solution

.open "C:/Users/Admin/OneDrive - batch/db.sqlite3"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing path like that:

```
C:\Users\Admin\"OneDrive - batch"\db.sqlite3
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Its not working. Same response: unknown option: -

Comment: It it possible to move your reseources from OneDrive to a local directory?